# xlsxwriter in range of dates

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am making an excelfile through xlsxwriter and I want to have a column with dates. More specifically the dates for the upcoming month. However, I can't seem to find a way to make a column of dates at all in xlsxwriter. The date column would then also be the index. Does anyone have a simple way to do this?

This is what I currently have: *(I have extracted only my date handling for the purpose of this question)*

```
from datetime import date
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('date_newexcel.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
worksheet.set_column('A:B', 30)

worksheet.write('A1', 'Formatted date', bold)
date_t  = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy'})
worksheet.write(0, 0, date(2018, 10, 15), date_t)

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, however you could try the [`write_datetime`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-number) method:

```
worksheet.write_datetime(0, 0, date(2018, 10, 15), date_t)
```

If you need to write the whole column with dates I'd iterate over the number of days you want (let's say `30`) and add 1 day at the date you write, using the [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) class:

```
d = date(2018, 10, 15)
for i in range(30):
    worksheet.write_datetime(i, 0, d, date_t)
    d += timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: I can get one date just fine, but I want to fill in a range of dates in the Date-column I am making. Do you know how?

Comment: So you mean adding consecutive dates to consecutive rows?